# How to restore PhpStorm settings from repository (at GitHub) after reinstall

Tags: phpstorm

I had to uninstall and reinstall PhpStorm. I'd like to get my settings back to what they were before uninstall. I've set up the Settings Repository (hosted at GitHub, presumably where my old settings are), but there is no option to reload the settings from the repository!!

Am I crazy?  What am I missing?

Version 2017.2.4

Comment: What is your Operating System ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything - settings are located separately from application itself and location depends on OS: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519. When you start PhpStorm again, it will automatically take all the settings from existing place so you can actually re-install the app as many times as you like.
If you exported them to Settings Repository, just go to File > Settings Repository, put in the URL and press "Overwrite Local" to download and import the settings.

Answer (score 0):

from phpStorm go to >> File -> Manage IDE Setting -> Restore Default Settings
it's working fine for all of version